How to Permanently Delete Files Folders in An Azure DevOps Branch
Can someone let me know if it's possible to permanently delete files a folders from Branches. I have deleted a file from my Branch which although removed from my Branch still exists in Commits, see image. Is it possible to delete the file entirely from ADO?


This is a git repo so what you are actually asking is how to alter the git version history.

Hi @JonathanDodds, thanks for getting in touch. Can you let me know how to alter the git version history?. Alternatively, is there an actual time-lapse that will automatically purge the history?

Automatically purging history is antithetical to the point of software version control. But you can do a squash merge to keep your main clean.

Based on your description, your requirement is to remove certain commit(s) from the commit history pushed to the branch of your repo rather than to remove directory/files from the branch.

You seemed to have a misunderstanding between the Files and Commits in Azure Repos. When we remove some Files from the branch in an Azure repo, it will push a commit to the Commits history; therefore, per that and later versions of our code, the folder/file is already removed. As a benefit of such version control, we are able to check the code/changes in that version(commit) and create a topic branch based on that version(commit) and revert our code to that version if needed. To revert to the old version is to use Pull Request to merge the old code version with the current one, which will also generate a commit to the history.

There is no way to remove the commit history from the original branch, which is by design of GIT not Azure DevOps and Azure GIT Repos simply use GIT for the code version control.
With that being said, if you insist to have a clean commit history, you may evaluate if it is possible to create a new empty repo or new branch with the expected version locally and save the backup files from the original branch into the new repo/branch and push that local repo/branch to remote Azure repo. Please discuss the necessity of this action with your developers first and backup your code to avoid any accidental data deletion.
